# Laravel 5.8 post comment with ajax request without reloading DOM

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm trying to post comments in my application without having to reload my page. I've got it working for deleting comments, but it isn't working for posting new ones. Can somebody please help??

**Script for ajax request**

```
// Add comments AJAX
$(".commentButton").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var comment = $("input[name=comment]").val();
    var token = $(this).data("token");

    $.ajax({
       url: "/comments/"+id,
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'JSON',
       data: {
           "id": id,
           "comment": comment,
           "_method": 'POST',
           "_token": token,
       },

       success: function(){
        $("#comment_"+id).append(comment);
           console.log('it works!');
       } 
    });
    console.log("It failed");
});
```

**CommentController**

```php
  public function store(Request $request, $recipe_id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'comment' => 'required|min:5|max:2000'
        ));

        $recipe = Recipe::find($recipe_id);

        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->name = auth()->user()->name;
        $comment->email = auth()->user()->email;
        $comment->comment = $request->comment;
        $comment->recipe()->associate($recipe); //I have relationship between 
        $comment->save();

        return $comment;
```

**Blade view where comments render**

```
<div class="col-12 currentComments">
                            <hr>
                        @foreach($recipe->comments as $comment)
                            <div id="comment_{{ $comment->id }}">
                                @if($comment->name == Auth()->user()->name)
                                    <p><a href="/user/{{$comment->name}}">{{$comment->name}}</a></p>
                                    <p class="comment">{{$comment->comment}}</p>
                                    <button class="deleteComment" data-id="{{ $comment->id }}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" >Delete Comment</button>
                                @else
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Where is this going worng? I know I'm missing something but I can't figure out what needs to be done. Fairly new to this. Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: I think you should load or get comments using ajax `get` also.

Comment: so make a separate ajax function for Load Comments after the post function?

Comment: In your browser go to inspect, then network  tab, then submit your comment and see if you are getting any errors in the response.

Comment: Yes, you should use ajax `get` to fetch the comments list instead of laravel `foreach` in blade.

Comment: @RashedHasan Okay. Will that allow me to render a new comment without page load?

Comment: Make a JS function with Get Ajax request to load comments. Call this function on Ready [ $(document).ready(function() { }) ] when you view Post page. In your Comment Post Ajax success, call this JS function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should get comments using `ajax` to view. You can try something like below. I hope it will help you to reload comments after saving new comment without page refresh.
In your `blade` file -

```
<div class="col-12 currentComments">
  <hr>
  <div id="allComments" class="allComments">
       <!--here your comments will render via ajax call-->
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="authuser" value="{{ Auth()->user()->name }}">      
</div>
```

In your `script` you can try something like -

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        comment_load();
        function comment_loadad()
        {
          $.ajax({
              url: '/get-comment-list',
              type: 'GET',
              success: function (response) {
                  var authuser = $("#authuser").val();
                  $.each(response, function (i, data) {
                    $('.allComments').append(
                          '<div id="comment_"'+ data.id + '>' +
                           (data.name == authuser ? 
                               '<p><a href="/user/'+data.name+'">' +data.name +'</a></p>' +
                               '<p class="comment">'+data.comment+'</p>' +
                               '<button class="deleteComment" data-id="'+data.id+'">Delete Comment</button>'
                                : '') 
                          +'</div>');
                    });

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    //console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And your `// Add comments AJAX` success method, please do `append` again -

```
success: function(data){                        
           var authuser = $("#authuser").val();
           $('.allComments').append(
                 '<div id="comment_"'+ data.id + '>' +
                   (data.name == authuser ? 
                   '<p><a href="/user/'+data.name+'">' +data.name +'</a></p>' +
                   '<p class="comment">'+data.comment+'</p>' +
                   '<button class="deleteComment" data-id="'+data.id+'">Delete Comment</button>'
                                : '') 
                 +'</div>');
           )
          $("input[name=comment]").val("");

 }
```